# How to fetch data by using Laravel Eloquent Relatinoships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm new to Laravel. Currently trying to use eloquent in one of my application. I've 3 database tables.. trips, trips_album, album_images. Table column are as follows..

**trips** - id(auto increment), trip_title, about_place, created_by
**trips_album** - id(auto_increment), trips_id(pointing to 'id' of trip table), album_status
**album_images** - album_id(pointing to 'id' of trip_album table), img_name

So, now i want all album images of trips, which belong to any particular user. How can i do this by using Laravel Eloquent Relationships. I'm using Laravel 4.2.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Wasn't laravel documentation helpful?

Comment: I tried laravel's 'has many through' relation. But, may be some where some thing i'm missing. Can't able to figure out what is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first, you may setting somethings.

```
class Trip extends Eloquent {
    public $table = "trips";
}
class Album extends Eloquent {
    public $table = "trips_album";
}
class Image extends Eloquent {
    public $table = "album_images";
}
```

After that, using "Has Many Through". Document [Here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through)

```
class Trip extends Eloquent {
    ...

    public function Images()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Image', 'Album', 'trip_id', 'album_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detail answer. it's working now. But, i've 1 doubt, that is.. "What is the convention to pass 3rd & 4th parameter"? Because, the moment i interchange the position of parameter it's showing error.