# Laravel - Eloquent where with relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code:

```
return Technology::WhereIn('uuid', $technologies)->get();
```

$technologies is an array of UUIDs and in my $technologies table I have a uuid field.

So this will return the technologies that match up with the UUIDs, but I also have an equipment_id in my technologies table and my end game goal is to get a list of equipment id's that belong to the technologies that match the UUIDs in my $technologies variable.

I could do a foreach loop and add the equipment id's to an array but I was wondering if there was a way to do some eloquent magic that would include the equipment relationship into the query.

Something like this: (this doesn't work)

```
return Technology::WhereIn('uuid', $technologies)->Equipment->get();
```

Comment: Please, read the docs one more time. https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

I think that was called "Has Many Through" Relationship.

I answered a same question at:

[How to fetch data by using Laravel Eloquent Relatinoships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325533/how-to-fetch-data-by-using-laravel-eloquent-relatinoships/26337468#26337468)

Answer (score 0):

If you just an array of equipment ids, you can use the `lists()` method on your model, like so :

```
return Technology::whereIn('uuid', $technologies)->lists('equipment_id');
```